# Another way to disable the headset-AudioManager not Working anymore

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I was able to disable the headset in the past for other devices, but now that I am testing different devices, the class I called will not work.  I assume the way I did it before no longer works, using AudioManager Method: setWiredDeviceConnectionState to disable the headset with reflection.  Is there any other way to do this or an update to make this way work?  Please help!!

Here is the code I currently use to disable the headset:

```
  AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    try {
        Class<?> cl = Class.forName("android.media.AudioManager");
        setWiredDeviceConnectionState = cl.getMethod("setWiredDeviceConnectionState", new Class[]{Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class});
        //4 is for the headset with microphone 8 is for headset without microphone
        //0 is for off and 1 is for on
        setWiredDeviceConnectionState.invoke(manager, new Object[]{4, 0, "device"});
        setWiredDeviceConnectionState.invoke(manager, new Object[]{8, 0, "device"});
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the exception when I run this code on the new phones:

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.raptorroboticstest-2/lib/arm64
W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setWiredDeviceConnectionState [int, int, class java.lang.String]
```